# pass data from view to form as choices

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Do not understand how to pass data obtained from `form.data` in view  as `choices` to form field. I would really appreciate any help.

So, here is what I am doing: I choose data using checkboxes at page, and then I need to display chosen data (their names) at the same page with additional textfield near each. Later all textfields must be filled and 'names' and inserted data must be sent to server.

As I understand for this I need to render data with textfield using form. I suppose it could be this one:

forms.py

```
import methods

class MultiTextField(SelectMultipleField):
    widget = widgets.TableWidget()
    option_widget = widgets.TextInput()

class SelectedForm(Form):
    choices = methods.selected()
    value = MultiTextField('value',choices = choices)
```

views.py

```
from forms import ...

selected_data = {}

def return_selected():
    return selected_data
```

methods.py

```
from views import return_selected

def selected():
    data = return_selected()
    choices = []
    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        for item in value:
            choices.append((item, key))
    return choices
```

Variable `selected_data` stores data that were chosen through other form.

If I run this code I got error `ImportError: cannot import name return_selected`. Probably it is because I import views in methods, methods in forms and forms in views o.O

I see no other way how to make what I need, but it does not work as it is.

Well, I found how to pass choices.

forms.py

```
class MultiTextField(SelectMultipleField):
    widget = widgets.TableWidget()
    option_widget = widgets.TextInput()

class SelectedForm(Form):
    name = MultiTextField()
```

views.py

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_work():
    selected = SelectedForm(request.form)
    choices = []
    for key, value in selected_data.iteritems():
        choices.append((key, value))
    selected.name.choices = choices
    return render_template('home.html', selected=selected)
```

It is possible to add form choices in views with `selected.name.choices = choices`.

But this form puts data in strange way:

home.html

```
<form name="selected" action="{{url_for('selected_work', url='result') }}" method="post">
    <p> {{selected.name}}</p>
<input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

in choices was lets say: [(1,"Apple"), (2,"Apple")] but html show label 'Apple' and near it textfield with inserted number 1 and again label 'Apple' with number 2 inserted in textfield.

When I submit form ofcourse it sends inserted data in textfield, which is ['1', '2']. But somehow I need obtain: [(Apple, 1 and value inserted in textfield),(Apple, 2, inserted value)].

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular dependency. Views import forms, which imports methods, which imports forms.

But your proposed solution is extremely dangerous. You are storing data at module level, which is absolutely not thread-safe and will lead to information leaking between users. Do not do this. Store the data in the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/), which is per-user.

Comment: I thought about session, but it won`t do the trick. I have 10 different forms at same page. each form is a list of checkboxes. user may choose any. all chosen values must be stored somewhere. I use global variable of dict type for this purpose. do not know how to use session for this.

Comment: I don't understand what the number of forms has to do with it. If you've got the data from the forms, you put in inside `request.session` instead of your global dict. You must not use a global dict.

Comment: If I do so, when using it in function, I got: RuntimeError('working outside of request context').

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Daniel for your advice about `session`. I store chosen data in session now.

Here is how I solved my task. I decided not to use wtforms form for rendering data chosen with checkboxes. I keep all choices in session

views.py

```
import methods
from forms import ...

def make_record(works):
if session['data']:
    if not works:
        pass
    else:
        for work in works:
            session['data'].append(work)
else:
    session['data'] = [works]

@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_work():
    demount = DemountForm(request.form)
    tile = TileForm(request.form)
    chosen = []
    for each in session['data']:
        chosen.append(each)
    selected = methods.get_selected(chosen)
    return render_template('home.html', demount=demount, tile=tile, selected = selected)

@app.route('/home/<path:url>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def select_work(url):
    db = url
    if db:
        form = DemountForm(request.form)
        work = form.name.data
        make_record(work)
    return redirect(url_for('show_work'))
```

methods.py

```
def get_selected(ids):
    selected = {}
    for each in ids:
        data = db_session.query(Work.name, Work.dimension).filter(Work.id==each).all()
        data = data[0]
        selected[each] = data
    return selected
```

home.html

```
{% if selected %}
    <div id="chosen">
        <form action="/home">
            {% for key, value in selected.iteritems() %}
                    {{value[0]}}<input type="text" id="{{key}}">{{value[1]}}<br>
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

In such way I obtained what I needed. On one page I got menu with checkboxes and div which display choices and textfields near each to insert additional data.